# Loop inside a heredoc function

Tags: php, wordpress

Maybe this has been asked many time but cant seem to find the correct fit. Im new to php and trying to do something crazy/wrong.

It's wordpress. I have a function that I reuse. I need to use a function because I pass params. Inside that function, I loop through to `echo` out html but keep getting "Notice array to string conversion".

```
function foo($bars) {
 // I have no idea the correct approach!
 foreach ($bars as $bar) {
  $big_bar = $bar;
 }

 echo <<<HTML
 <div>
   $big_bar;
 </div>
HTML;
}
```

The aim is to loop through `$bars` inside a html function. How, please?

Comment: what's the value of `$bars`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Its just another array.

Comment: _“Its just another array”_ – no, it likely is a multi-dimensional array, because only then that error message would make sense here.

Comment: As @CBroe says, it can be array of array that is why you are getting error like this.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Not array of array, just `$bars = [1,2,3,4]` But an answer below worked. Still trying to get my head around php, sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more ways to do this. If you wanted to echo every value in `$bars`:

```
function foo($bars) {
  foreach ($bars as $bar) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div>
$bar
</div>
HTML;
  }
}
```

You don't need a nowdoc for such a simple example:

```
function foo($bars) {
  foreach ($bars as $bar) {
    echo "<div>".$bar."</div>";
  }
}
```

If you supply an array of strings to `foo`, both of the above will work. However, if you supply an array of arrays, you will get the notice from PHP. Make sure you are passing in the correct input!

Comment: the exercise may have been simplified to clear away the fluff, and they may still want to know how to do that in particular

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to loop inside heredoc, there

```
<?php
$map=function($a,$f){return join("\n",array_map($f,$a));};
$data=[1,2,3];

$select = <<<HERE
<select>
 {$map($data,function($item){return"
  <option>$item</option>
 ";})}
</select>
HERE;

print $select;
```

or even this

```
<?php
$map=function($a,$f){return join("\n",array_map($f,$a));};
$data=[1,2,3];

$select = "
<select>
 {$map($data,function($item){return"
  <option>$item</option>
 ";})}
</select>
";

print $select;
```

Comment: While the question is worded a bit poorly, this is the only answer that actually answers it.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? This code looks fairly obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to get output like this or may this help you.

```
    function foo($bars) 
    {
        $big_bar = '';

        foreach ($bars as $bar) {
            $big_bar .= $bar;
         }

         echo "<div>'".$big_bar."'</div>";
    }
```

You `$bars` array should be like this,

```
$bars = array("0"=>"first","1"=>"second");
```

Otherwise you will get error of

> Notice: array to string conversion

.